# Change existing JSON message format into new with fields in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

We have to do some changes in existing JSON response and it requires to modify existing c# code too. Till now I've tried but don't get the exact idea about the formatting as it is new for me.
Can any one please check and suggest the changes in below code?

**Existing JSON message:**

```
"hotel_room_types": {
    "QUEEN": {
      "code": "QUEEN",
      "bed_type": {
        "standard": [
          5
        ],
        "custom": []
      },
      "extra_bed_type": {
        "standard": [
          5
        ],
        "custom": []
      },    
      "accessibility": "compliant_with_local_laws_for_disabled",    
      "room_smoking_policy": "non_smoking"
    }   
  }
```

In above JSON message we have to replace the "bed_type" and "extra_bed_type" with "bed_configurations" and "extra_bed_configurations" in below newly provided format by client:

```
"hotel_room_types": {
    "QUEEN": {
      "code": "QUEEN",
 "bed_configurations": [
           [{
             "type": "standard",
             "code": 3,
             "count": 1
             }],
           [{
              "type": "standard",
              "code": 1,
              "count": 2
             }]
         ],
"extra_bed_configurations": [
           [{
             "type": "standard",
             "code": 900302,
             "count": 1
             },
             {
              "type": "custom",
              "name": "Rollaway with wheel locks and adjustable height",
              "count": 1
             }]
         ],
          "accessibility": "compliant_with_local_laws_for_disabled",    
      "room_smoking_policy": "non_smoking"
    }   
  }
```

**Existing C# code to generate the JSON response message format:**

```
public class HotelRoomType
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public Amenities room_amenities { get; set; }
    public string room_size { get; set; }
    public string room_size_units { get; set; }
    public BedType bed_type { get; set; }
    public BedType extra_bed_type { get; set; }     
    public RoomViewType room_view_type { get; set; }
    public string accessibility { get; set; }
    public MaxOccupancy max_occupancy { get; set; }
    public string room_smoking_policy { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code to fill the data in required fields of JSON message its inside a method which contains lines of code so I get it separately:

```
HotelRoomType hotelrmtype = new HotelRoomType();
hotelrmtype.bed_type = Common.GetStandardBedTypeMappingID(rm.BedType);                                                        
if (rm.NumOfBed > 1)
   hotelrmtype.extra_bed_type = hotelrmtype.bed_type; //same as bed type

hotelrmtypeDict.Add(rm.Code, hotelrmtype);  //Binding Data into Dictionary.
```

**GetStandardBedTypeMappingID() contains :**

```
public static CRS.TripConnect.BedType GetStandardBedTypeMappingID(short code)
{
    CRS.TripConnect.BedType tripConnectBedType = new CRS.TripConnect.BedType();
    List<int> standardBedTypes = new List<int>();
    List<object> customBedTypes = new List<object>();
    tripConnectBedType.standard = standardBedTypes;
    tripConnectBedType.custom = customBedTypes; //These is blank.
    short id = 0;
    switch (code)
    {
        case 10:               
            id = 3;
            break;
        case 20:                //  20  Queen   Q   5
            id = 5;
            break;
        case 30:               //  30   Double  D   1
            id = 1;
            break;
        case 40:               //  40   Twin    T   8
            id = 8;
            break;
    }
    standardBedTypes.Add(id);
    return tripConnectBedType;
}
```

**Update:** With the help of @Sam Answer below I have modified the code:

```
public class HotelRoomType
{
    //Added following properties
    public List<List<Bed_Configurations>> bed_configurations { get; set; }
    public List<List<Extra_Bed_Configurations>> extra_bed_configurations { get; set; }
}
```

Created two new classes as:

```
public class Bed_Configurations
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }   
}

public class Extra_Bed_Configurations
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Now the question is: How to fill these two list?**

I'm trying to achieve this like below but it is giving me conversion error.

```
Bed_Configurations bdConfig = new Bed_Configurations();
bdConfig.type = "Standard";
bdConfig.code = Common.GetStandardBedTypeMappingIDnew(rm.BedType);
bdConfig.count = rm.NumOfBed;
hotelrmtype.bed_configurations.Add(bdConfig);
```

**Error Message:** 
[image]
Please Advise the changes in the above code so as to get the required JSON message. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I can recommend 2 tools: 1) http://json2csharp.com - copy/paste your JSON and it will produce C# classes. 2) If you're using VS, you can copy your JSON and go to `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON As Classes`. This will also generate C# classes. You can then work out for yourself the changes in properties and code. Unfortunately, we aren't able to do all the work for you. SO is designed for specific problems, and this question runs the risk of falling into "doing the work for you" - plus there might be other parts of your code that depend on the classes. Hope this helps, somewhat :)

Comment: bed_type and bed_configurations are not of same type. one is object and other is collection. So, am not sure, your model HotelRoomType is correct here.

Comment: You should consider separating the models you use in your own code from the models you use to talk to the clients data provider so that any changes to the structure can be localized to the adapter. You aren't just changing names here, you're changing structure as well, the original types were just one object, now they're a collection, how should your application cope with that change if we forget the name change for a second?

Comment: correct @sam, I have removed it please check. That was added by mistake as I was trying to implement the changes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RootClass
{
    public HotelRoomType hotel_room_types { get; set; }
}
public class HotelRoomType
{

    public BedModelAndDetails QUEEN { get;set; }
}
public class BedModelAndDetails
{
    public string accessibility { get; set; }
    public string room_smoking_policy { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }

    //public BedType bed_type { get; set; }
    public object bed_type { get; set; }
    //public BedType extra_bed_type { get; set; }
    public object extra_bed_type { get; set; }
    public List<List<BedConfiguration>> bed_configurations { get; set; }
    public List<List<BedConfiguration>> extra_bed_configurations { get; set; }
}

public class BedType
{
    public List<int> standard { get; set; } 
    public List<int> custom { get; set; } 
}
public class BedConfiguration
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; } 
    public int count { get; set; } 
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReplaceJson()
{
    var inputJson1 = "{\"hotel_room_types\": {\"QUEEN\": {\"code\": \"QUEEN\", \"bed_type\": {\"standard\": [5],\"custom\": [] }, \"extra_bed_type\": { \"standard\": [5], \"custom\": [] },\"accessibility\": \"compliant_with_local_laws_for_disabled\", \"room_smoking_policy\": \"non_smoking\" } " +"}}";
    var input1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(inputJson1, new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore});

    var inputJson2 = "{\"hotel_room_types\": {\"QUEEN\": {\"code\": \"QUEEN\",\"bed_configurations\": [[{\"type\": \"standard\",\"code\": 3,\"count\": 1}],[{\"type\": \"standard\",\"code\": 1,\"count\": 2}]],\"extra_bed_configurations\": [[{\"type\": \"standard\",\"code\": 900302,\"count\": 1},{\"type\": \"custom\",\"name\": \"Rollaway with wheel locks and adjustable height\",\"count\": 1}]],\"accessibility\": \"compliant_with_local_laws_for_disabled\",\"room_smoking_policy\": \"non_smoking\"} }}";
    var input2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClass>(inputJson2);

    //var finalInput = new RootClass();
    //finalInput.hotel_room_types = inputJson1
    //input1.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.bed_configurations = input2.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.bed_configurations;
    //input1.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.extra_bed_configurations = input2.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.extra_bed_configurations;
    input1.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.bed_type = input2.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.bed_configurations;
    input1.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.extra_bed_type = input2.hotel_room_types.QUEEN.extra_bed_configurations;       
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: thanks @sam it somewhat help me and now I have updated the question please check and advise if you have any idea.

Comment: bdConfig is intance of class but not instance of System.Generic.Collections.List<Bed_Configurations>.  And that the reason why you are getting error.  You are invoking "Add" function on  class Bed_Configurations. Class name is poorly named ( as plural).

Comment: List<List<Bed_Configurations>> bedConfigurationsList = new List<List<Bed_Configurations>>
            {
                new List<Bed_Configurations> { bdConfig }
            };